# Keyboard input between select() in Python

Tags: python, select, stdin, readline, keyboard-input

I write some codes to get the input from keyboard and also check something is alive or not:

```
import sys
from select import select

timeout = 10
while is_alive(): # is_alive is a method to check some stuffs, might take 5 secs
    rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if rlist:
        s = sys.stdin.readline()
        print repr(s)
        handle(s) # handle is a method to handle and react according to input s
```

I found that when the keyboard input ends outside of the waiting in `select()` (usually it ends during the 5 secs of `is_alive()`), the `if rlist:` will get false.

I can understand why but I don't know how to solve it.

And there is still another question related to the situation mentioned above, sometimes `readline()` will return the last line of my input when some inputs are located across different `select()` waiting.

That means, if I enter **'abc\n'** and unfortunately the **'\n'** located outside of wating in `select()` (that means, when I press ***Enter***, the program are executing other parts, such as `is_alive()`), and then if I enter **'def\n'** and this time the ***Enter*** pressed successfully located within `select()`, I'll see the `s` from `readline()` becomes **'def\n'** and the first line is disappeared.

Is there any good solution to solve two issues above? I'm using FreeBSD 9.0.

Comment: it would be interesting to know the OS you are working on...

Comment: I found it might related the codes in is_alive(). In that function I use Popen() to execute some ssh commands to check if some servers are still online. After I replace those with only sleep() in is_alive(), no words disappear anymore.

Comment: That makes [answering easy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13739851/296974)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code in `is_alive()` calls `ssh`, this will eat up the stdin.

Try starting `ssh` with the `-n` option or with a re-directed `stdin`.

The latter would work with

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.stdin.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about ssh will eat up stdin.